# Python: how can I use dates in Numba?

Tags: python, numpy, numba

Numba's documentation provides this example, to show numba is compatible with numpy's datetime64:

```
import numba
import numpy as np    
@numba.autojit(nopython=True)
def foo():
    date = np.datetime64('2014-01-01')
    return date
foo()
```

However, if I run it I get this error message.
Why? How can I use dates in Numba? I'd need to comapre variables to specific dates (if x=1-May-2015 then do something). The only thing I can think of is to extract year, month and day to separate numeric variables and run the comparison on those.

```
numba.typing.templates.UntypedAttributeError: Failed at nopython (nopython frontend)
Unknown attribute "datetime64" of type Module(<module 'numpy' from 'C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.pyc'>)
```

I searched everywhere, but Numba's documentation is appallingly poor, and I haven't found anything here nor on other forums. Thanks!

Comment: Which version of numba are you using? And can you provide a link to that example in the docs? (I can't find it)

Comment: I am running numba 0.17.0 and numpy 1.9.2. The example was in the docs of version 0.11: http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.11/types.html#datetimes I don't understand if this functionality has been removed, or if I am misreading something

Comment: The datetime support in 0.11 was experimental (see [release notes](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.20.0/release-notes.html#version-0-11)), and it was later removed and refactored. Better to use the docs of the version you are using (or the docs of the latest stable version). Do you have a specific question about using datetimes?

Comment: I see. I have a loop in Numba where I have to check if the values of an array are a specific month and year. I solved it creating an int array with just the month, one with just the year, and setting an if which checks both (I don't care about the day). Is there a better way?